# How to make it such that if comments have been edited before, an "edited" permanent message will be displayed beside the comment?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to make it such that if comments have been edited before, an "edited" permanent message will be displayed beside the comment? So that everyone will be able to see that the comment has been edited before. (it'll be good if i can keep a copy of the original pre-edited message too, but if thats too difficult, i'm just hoping to display an "edited" permanent message will be displayed beside the comment.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   body = models.TextField()

class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def edit_own_comment(request, post_id):
    context = {}
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=post_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateCommentForm(request.POST or None, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your comment has been edited', extra_tags='editedcomment')
            return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': comment.post.slug }))

    form = UpdateCommentForm(
            initial = {
                    "body": comment.body,
            }
        )

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/edit_comment.html', context)


class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post=self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Comment
  fields = ['body']

 def save(self, commit=True):
  comment = self.instance
  comment.body = self.cleaned_data['body']

  if commit:
   comment.save()
  return comment
```

detail.html

```
  {% for comment in blog_post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.name}}
  {{ comment.body }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Ankush described the best possible solution you can have, add this to your `Comment` **model**:

```
edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then in your **view** whenever the comment gets edited before calling `comment.save()` do this:

```
comment.edited = True
```

And in your **html** where you list comments do this:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.name }} : {{ comment.body }}</p>
    {% if comment.edited %}
        <p>edited</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "edited" boolean field in your database which will work as a flag (with False value by default). Whenever the update operation will happen you will set this flag to True. And you can use this field into your templates to make "edited" text visible before message.

Comment: Hi @Ankush, thanks for input, so basically I will need a new field? and theres no way for me to do it without a new field? If so, could you share how I can "connect" that field to the update operation? meaning how is it possible to set this flag to True when i update?